# static images not showing in flask when deploying with vercel

Tags: python, flask, deployment, web-deployment, vercel

I am trying to deploy my flask application in Vercel. I followed this tutorial:
https://dev.to/andrewbaisden/how-to-deploy-a-python-flask-app-to-vercel-2o5k

It mainly works for deploying my app, but unfortunately my static images/videos are not showing.
My dir structure is:

```
root
----- index.py
----- vercel.json
----- requirements.txt
----- another files
----- static -
             video.webm
             video.mp4
----- templates
```

My vercel.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./index.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python"
        },
        {
            "src": "/static/**",
            "use": "@vercel/static"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "index.py"
        }
    ]
}
```

I dont know whats happening, because templates are working and routes too, but static files are not showing at all.

Comment: Is it relevant? Could you show the code line you define `app`? In my case I defined my app with explicit indication that it is static folder. `app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder="./static")` And it works fine

Comment: I'm facing the same issue as well. the files/folders are uploaded but vercel isn't showing them up? does anyone have a solution to this problem